# How do I define a datetime field in a python dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

trying to get the syntax of the Python 3.7 new dataclass right.

if I want to include a datetime value in my dataclass,

```
import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyExampleWithDateTime:
    mystring: str
    myint: int
    mydatetime: ???
```

What should I write for ??? for a datetime field?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Like this:

```
@dataclass
class MyExampleWithDateTime:
    mystring: str
    myint: int
    mydatetime: datetime.datetime
```

Comment: Are there any useful tips for making this json serializable outside of creating a customer encoder? Referring to the error message: `TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable` that results from: `ex = MyExampleWithDateTime('a', 1, datetime.datetime.now())`. and then: `json.dumps(asdict(ex))` results in: `

Comment: JSON does not have datetime.datetime objects. You could store the components of `mydatetime` as numbers (e.g. `mydt_yr`, `mydt_mo`, `mydt_d`, etc.), then define a @property `mydatetime` to combine the units, with a setter to split out the units.

Comment: Or, you could represent the `datetime.datetime` object as an ISO 8601-formatted string, then do something similar with a property and a setter.

Comment: @eksortso checkout orjson

Comment: `json.dumps(asdict(ex), default=str)` will transform datetimes into str (default representation). It will do the same for all other types that aren't JSON serializable. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump